# Bind Meteor's client to separate DDP server

Tags: meteor, ddp

I'd like to bind my frontend APP which is built in Meteor to a standalone server that exposes its API via DDP connection. I have this server's DDP connection URL, but how do i actually connect to it from my frontend APP?

Is there a way in Meteor to set the default DDP connection which frontend APP should use to a custom value (URL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
DDP.connect(url)
```

Documentation is here: https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html

You will need to manage the connection yourself (ie reconnect when it fails)

Answer (score 0):

Try use the [custom ddp connection package](https://atmospherejs.com/xneon/ddp-backend).

> Run `meteor add xneon:ddp-backend`
>
> Set the environment variable `BACKEND_URL` to the URL of the remote server